# HashMap containsKey

Tags: java, testing, junit, hashmap

Hi I'm trying to run some junit tests but I have a problem with HashMaps, basically I have to create a RentalAgency for cars
So I have

```
  public class RentalAgencyTest{
    private List<Vehicle> theVehicles;
    private Map<Client,Vehicle> rentedVehicles;
    private RentalAgency renault;
    private Vehicle twingo;
    private Vehicle punto;
    private Client client1;
    private Client client2;
  }

  @Before
  public void before(){
    this.theVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    this.rentedVehicles = new HashMap <Client,Vehicle>();
    this.renault = new RentalAgency(theVehicles, rentedVehicles);
    this.punto = new Vehicle("Fiat", "punto", 2000, 6);
    this.twingo = new Vehicle("Renault", "twingo", 1998, 4);
    this.client1 = new Client("Pignon", 21);
    this.client2 = new Client("Leblanc", 21);
   }
```

And the problem is with this Test :

```
@Test
public void testAllRentedVehicles(){
  this.rentedVehicles.put(this.client1, this.punto);
  this.rentedVehicles.put(this.client2, this.twingo);
  assertTrue(this.rentedVehicles.containsKey(this.twingo));
  assertTrue(this.rentedVehicles.containsKey(this.punto));
  assertTrue(this.rentedVehicles.size() == 2);
}
```

With some workaround I figured that the assert on the size is true, so the rentedVehicles hashmap has 2 vehicles indeed but it doesn't seems like the keys are this.twingo and this.punto as I expected it to be and I can't figure out why or what are they

Comment: The keys are `this.client1` and `this.client2`, the first argument to `put` is the key. Did you mean to use `containsValue` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I just figured that on my own and felt dumb haha, thanks for the reply anyways !

Comment: Or maybe, by mistake, you reversed the key and value types in your declaration of `rentedVehicles`? Maybe you meant `Map<Vehicle,Client> rentedVehicles` ?

Comment: No, the problem was that I used the wrong method (containsKey instead of containsValue)